# Redundant "North American History" tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We have an existing "North America" tag and there now appears to be a "North American History" tag too. Since all of the tags on History SE are (or should be) about history, this new tag seems redundant.

Not only that, but it's been added to a number of questions over the last couple of days that don't even relate to North America, such as [this one](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/34273/what-evidence-is-there-that-lenin-died-because-he-was-poisoned) about Lenin and [this one](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/34413/if-the-ch-in-dynasty-was-so-short-lived-why-was-china-named-for-it) about China.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nuke it.

In the presence of [north-america](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/north-america), which has 41 questions (More than thrice the number of questions using the other tag), has a better usage excerpt and due to the fact that it is hosted on History.SE implies that the tag is about history, we ought to destroy the redundant tag.

I propose that we retag the 12 questions tagged with [north-american-history](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/north-american-history) with the pre-existing [north-america](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/north-america) and [let the system destroy the redundant tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71123/i-accidentally-created-a-tag-how-do-i-delete-it).

Comment: I agree, we should swap "North American History" for "North America" in cases where it actually applies and just remove it in the others.

Comment: Completely concur. Aaaaaad....done.